# Parsing data from EVA format

Tags: java, regex, awk

I'm trying to fetch data from [EVA](http://www.laze.org/eva/index.html) binary database, where fields were separated by some special symbols. So far I've managed to convert date into a XML-like text file of a following format. Notice how the order of the fields varies and that not all of them are obligatory.

```
<251>id1<230><223>author1<228><215>title1<223><230>year1<225><232>location1<226>
<251>id2<230><223>author2<228><230>year2<225><232>location2<226><215>title2<223>
<251>id3<230><230>year2<225><232>location2<226><215>title2<223>
```

Each line is separate entry, and for each of them I would like to get something like

```
251=id1
223=author1
```

etc.

Now I am struggling to parse data from it. I usually used the explode function and define delimiters, but I cant do that here because then I would lose information to which field a certain substring belongs.

Maybe I should mention that in the end I want to generate a CSV file, so maybe there is a way to parse it directly from my text file skipping redundant process of parsing each datum separately jut to merge it then again in another format.

Comment: whats the second number for ?

Comment: the second number is redundant; it just tells that the block is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[<>]+"
    OFS="="
}
{
    for (i=2;i<NF;i+=3) {
        print $i, $(i+1)
    }
    print ""
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
251=id1
223=author1
215=title1
230=year1
232=location1

251=id2
223=author2
230=year2
232=location2
215=title2

251=id3
230=year2
232=location2
215=title2
```

After re-reading your question this is probably closer to what you really want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[<>]+"; OFS="," }

{
    for (i=2;i<NF;i+=3) {
        if (!seenName[$i]++) {
            names[++numNames] = $i
        }
        n2v[NR,$i] = $(i+1)
    }
}

END {
    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", names[nameNr], (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
    }

    for (recNr=1; recNr<=NR; recNr++) {
        for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
            name = names[nameNr]
            printf "%s%s", n2v[recNr,name], (nameNr<numNames?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
251,223,215,230,232
id1,author1,title1,year1,location1
id2,author2,title2,year2,location2
id3,,title2,year2,location2
```

If not then update your question to show the actual output you do want given the input you posted.